# Why does my eudiometer have this excess volume at the top?

Tags: gas-laws, stoichiometry, equipment

It looks like this:

[image: eudiometer]

The measurements start at 2 mL and the volume remaining in the top seems to be greater than 1 mL. What is the purpose? I am trying to measure hydrogen gas.

Comment: I'd guess that because that is a cheap way to make an eudiometer. If you had makings down at the curved end then the bias in the marking and actual volume is probably hard to control. Down the tube the diameter would be more consistent. // I'd guess the problem is mass producing the markings in a machine.